# MySQL Proxy "Backends are down" in Browser

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, proxy, database-connection

I am able to access my database via mysql proxy through Workbench but when I try to browse to a page on my internal network that connects to the database I get:

```
HY000: (proxy) all backends are down
```

I get this on any machine, including the one running the proxy and Workbench.

The code I use to connect to the database is:

```
$user = 'view_user', $pass = 'european', $database = 'db2014', $host = '192.168.0.13', $port = '4040';

parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . $host . ';port=' . $port . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, FALSE);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, TRUE);

        $this->exec("SET NAMES utf8");

        $this->exec("SET character_set_results = 'utf8',
             character_set_client = 'utf8', 
             character_set_connection = 'utf8',
             character_set_database = 'utf8',  
             character_set_server = 'utf8'");
```

The credentials are definitely correct and are the same as the ones I'm using in Workbench.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this won't work when it should!?

---

My proxy config:

```
"C:\MySQL Proxy\bin\mysql-proxy" --proxy-backend-addresses="192.168.0.10:3306" --proxy-backend-addresses="192.168.0.11:3306" --proxy-address="127.0.0.1:4040"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. Just posting incase someone else has this problem.

The issue was that `--proxy-address` was set to the local host when it should be set to the machines actual IP, i.e. 192.168.0.13 in my case and not 127.0.0.1!

Comment: That wouldn't cause this problem. It would prevent you from connecting *to the proxy* from another host. It should really be set to `:6446` or whatever your proxy port is, without an IP address at all, so it will listen at 0.0.0.0, i.e. all interfaces, unless you have a specific reason (e.g. security) for listening at only one of them.